# Call JavaScript Function after list data has successfully updated via quick edit

Tags: 2013, rest, web-services, ajax, promises

I am trying to call a custom JavaScript function after content is saved into a list via quick edit. Once the data is saved, I would like to make an AJAX call to get the newly updated items. I do not want to run the code until everything has properly saved, and I do not want to force wait.

Is there some type of promise I can use or something I can watch for to call my AJAX function after the save takes place?

Comment: I *think* you can do this using Webhooks. I haven't done anything with Webhooks myself but a quick Google search for "sharepoint webhooks" did come up with some results.

Comment: Just saw this. Looks like webhooks are coming to SharePoint Online https://twitter.com/paolopia/status/664006660051046400

Comment: Hey Rob, thanks for the direction! I looked into it a bit and I am partially thinking just scrapping the idea of using the quick edit and using the web services to POST and GET the data. This way, I can control when the call can occur.